# I am not sure how the array of the code is being traced?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, trace

I don't understand how the array is being traced. I feel like I know it but then I mess it up again. I get how the values are being swapped but I am still getting confused. I wrote my questions as comments besides my code. Can someone help me trace that part?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int i,j,temp;

    for (j=1; j<5; j++) 
        for (i=0; i<5-j; i=i+2) 
        {
            printf("%d %d\n",i,i+j); //I got this part right
            temp = a[i]; //from here I get confused
            a[i] = a[i+j]; //how is the addition inside working??
            a[i+j] = temp; //temp = the index's value
        }
            for (i=0; i<5; i++)
            printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i,a[i]);//what is i supposed to be here??
}

Output:
0 1
2 3
0 2
2 4
0 3
0 4
a[0] = 2 //from here on I get lost
a[1] = 1
a[2] = 5
a[3] = 4
a[4] = 3
```

Comment: The sequence of assignments in the loop is swapping `a[i]` with `a[i+j]`, using `temp` as an intermediate value during the swap.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you print your whole array in every loop, that way you can see how values are moving, for example in step in you swap 0,1 element so array is {2,1,3,4,5}, then 2,3 so {2,1,4,3,5}, then 0,2 so {4,1,2,3,5} , 2,4,=> {4,1,5,3,2}, 0,3 {3,1,5,4,2},0 4 {2,1,5,4,3}

Comment: @ThomasKühn May be I understood the question wrong, but he did wanted to know how the value of array reached to the printed values. Maybe you can clarify the question better thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you don't know much about C programming. So here is a bit about arrays:

1. An array (here: `int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5}`) is contiguously allocated blocks of memory.
2. An array a[n] is of size 'n'(stores n values of array type, here `int`) and is index from 0 to n-1. Meaning each of the n values are accessed from `a[0]` to `a[n-1]`.
3. There are multi-dimensional arrays (read it up!).

The logic given here:

```
temp = a[i];   //temp gets a[i]'s value and not the value of i
a[i] = a[i+j];
a[i+j] = temp;
```

This is the standard swap(a,b) operation using a temporary variable temp. Just that 'a' and 'b' here are elements of an array.

The loops are designed in such a way to access different elements of the array in each iteration. This shuffles the array.

So obviously:

```
printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i,a[i]); // i here is the index used to access a's ith element
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong. I was simply trying to do the math and change that position's value. I have to open up space and move the old number out to put the new number in. Then the old number will go to empty space that's left. It's actually just simply swapping but it helps to see it this way better.

So in {1,2,3,4,5}, if I try to put a[3]=4 in a[1]=2, the value 4 will go to a[1].
a[1] which had 2 will have to get out and a[3] which had 4 will move in.
The 2 that was out will go in the place where 4 was before in a[3]=2.

So now a[1]=4 and a[3]=2. 
So the swapped array will now look like {1,4,3,2,5}